# Visual Studio toggle terminal with one shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

Only Visual Studio, not code. This is the 2022 Community Edition, but can also use 2019. I want to use one shortcut that will both open and close the terminal. Searched but no answers. I find a setting to open the terminal with a shortcut but none to close it as well. Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can try "control shift `" if you are on window

Comment: You are talking about visual studio and not code? Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Press from the keyboard and toggle your vs code terminal
(control+Backtick)

**ctr+`**

note: I am using mac

Comment: Not vs code, visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> will close the terminal window if it has focus. There is no global 'close terminal' in Visual Studio.

An alternative to using the terminal in Visual Studio could be to use the 'quake mode' in [Windows Terminal](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj5lNK_rub3AhVPQEEAHZl7BhAQFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fen-gb%2Fp%2Fwindows-terminal%2F9n0dx20hk701&usg=AOvVaw1eFHni9DxMo8GzE3-V5853) (assuming you are on Windows) by pressing the <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> to quickly open/close a terminal at the top of your screen.